# How to pass php variable to html template from Database in WordPress

Tags: php, wordpress, templates

I'm making my own WP plugin, which has a text field containing some template, which I save to the database (table=templates, field=template), something like this:

```
<div class="myclass">
    <p>Hello {$user_name}</p>
</div>
```

Then I'm trying to show a message to a user:

```
<php
 $user_name = "Bob";

 $template_query = 'select * from ' . $wpdb->get_blog_prefix();
 $template_query .= 'templates where id='.$some_id;
 $template_data = $wpdb->get_row( $template_query, ARRAY_A );
    
 $template = $template_data['template'];
 
 echo $template; 
 ?>
```

And it is output "Hello {$user_name}" instead of "Hello Bob"

I can not get how to pass PHP variables to HTML throw the database.

I'll be thankful for any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the DB `$template` will contain just a plain text string, not PHP.
You will have to replace the placeholder `{$user_name}` in `$template` with the value in `$user_name` through PHP.

E.g.:

Instead of

`echo $template;`

Try:

`echo str_replace('{$user_name}', $user_name, $template);`

which will output:

`Hello Bob`

*Also note that the `?` is missing from your opening `<?php` tag.*

Comment: I've also modified a little bit str_replace ( %% instead {$}) and replaced a single variable with an array to have the ability to replace several values in the template: $search = array('%user_first_name%', '%user_last_name%'); $replace = array($user_first_name, $user_last_name); $template=str_replace($search, $replace, $template_data['template']);   Is it correct way to do it like this?

Comment: Cheers City. It's a bit hard to read due to formatting of your comment, but that seems legit, yes! There's lots of ways to do things like this using e.g. `preg_replace()`, `printf()`, `vprintf()` as you wish :).
Please mark the answer as the correct one, thanks!